# asyncio not working on AWS Lambda (python 3.6)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6, python-asyncio

This works on my local machine but on AWS Lambda I get the below-mentioned error.

```
import asyncio
import os

async def abc():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("abc")

def handler(event, context):
    print("RANDOM")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(abc())
```

Error:

```
A Future or coroutine is required: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/index.py", line 11, in handler
    loop.run_until_complete(abc())
  File "/var/task/asyncio/base_events.py", line 296, in run_until_complete
    future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
  File "/var/task/asyncio/tasks.py", line 516, in async
    raise TypeError('A Future or coroutine is required')
TypeError: A Future or coroutine is required
```

Locally I run it by calling `handler("random_1", "random_2")`

And on AWS it's being triggered by an event.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues on lambdas and asyncio some times and I never understood it.

Can You try with a newer python version?

I'm using python 3.8 with `asyncio.run` instead of get_event_loop + run_until_complete and it works.